# What functions does the usb mouse driver use?

Tags: operating-system, usb, driver, protocols

I have a problem understanding how all the usb protocol works (possibly some OS stuff too) and what things are done via software/hardware.
If I decide to write a mouse driver...

- How does the driver read data? Is there a buffer where the usb host puts all the received stuff?
- Who provides the software/functions to access that "buffer"?
- Could the protocol be emulated with some digital pins that would pull up and down 2 data cables? So... any serial protocol could be emulated with a sufficient cpu power and some digital inputs and outputs, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

> How does the driver read data? Is there a buffer where the usb host puts all the received stuff?

That's the thing. The usb host controller (xhci) doesn't receive stuff. The driver has to ask for data to the controller. Usb controllers are PCI so the CPU gives PCI devices the possibility of reserving some portion of its physical address space. When a driver writes to that portion it writes in registers of the controller instead of RAM. PCI devices are DMA. They read/write RAM directly. You can put some data structures in RAM and the controller can read/write it directly. The data can represent anything like an operation that you want the controller to do.

For mouses, the driver has to use a timer. Every 8ms or so (reported by the mouse), the os asks the controller to asks its state to the mouse. The mouse will thus answer with what buttons are pressed and its movement (something like that).

Comment: But in this story you tell me, who construct and parse the packets? The controller, right? Adn that process is transparent to the guy programming the driver?

Comment: You actually need to construct the packets yourself and place them in RAM. The xhci will read them for you and electrically send them to the USB device. Overall, it almost is like you do most of the work, but the xhci does help because its interface is good. It has circular lists in RAM and reads them automatically. It also has timers for Interrupt Endpoints (like keyboards and mouses) so you don't need to use a CPU timer.

Comment: I was not clear, by packets I mean all the first part and last part of the electrical signal + the sync part + the encoding too (NRZI encoding), is that done by the xhci?

Comment: A driver is software. At this point, you don't care about electrical signals. You use the software interface of the processor to write PCI registers and the xhci does the rest for you. XHCI is a software interface standard. The xhci spec doesn't specify electrical signals or anything. The implementation of the xhci standard can vary in the actual circuitry within the electronic chip. I use xhci to refer to both the chip implementing the standard and the software interface standard. Might be wrong to do that but even Intel calls the chip an xHC in the spec.